# PDA Internal ftp files copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ftp, intermec

Im trying to make a windows script for making a retrieval from a PDA (INTERMEC CN70). The fun part of this pda is that what i try to do is implemented in activesync, but not more supported at my place of work.

So as the files generated by the pda is saved in an internal FTP of the pda and is connected in an Ethernet dock, I made an easy script to connect to the internal FTP, the issue is that i'm not an script rock star and once inside i don't know how to copy the files with the script, i seerched options like robocopy or xcopy but i don't know how to make this commands work for not overwriting the files.

I post my script here

```
@ECHO OFF
SET /p ippda=PDA ACTUAL IP?:
IF "%ippda%"=="" GOTO Faliure
explorer ftp://intermec:cr52401@%ippda%/
Goto End
:Faliure
ECHO IP faliure
PAUSE
:END
```

Thanks for your time^^

Comment: You don't use Explorer to automate FTP downloads. Explorer is a user interface application, not a scripting tool. You can Google FTP commands, or search this site for them. If the PDA's FTP supports standard commands, then you can find existing questions here or on [su] about which commands are available. Or you can just type `ftp /?` for the command line options, and then `ftp` followed by enter to start the command line FTP utility, which will give you a prompt like `ftp>`, at which point you can type `help` for a list of the commands (type `quit` to exit FTP).

Comment: i used explorer because is the only way that the guide says you can access to this files. This system is really new for me and is kinda overwhelming...

Comment: As I said, Explorer is a user-interface tool, not for scripting. The reason you used it isn't important; what's important is that it's not going to work via scripting using Explorer, and you need to research using ftp.exe instead. Read my last comment again. :-) If the only option available is browsing via Explorer's ftp, you're not going to succeed in automating it from a batch file.

Comment: Start at [su] - here's a search link to get you started: https://superuser.com/search?q=%5Bwindows%5D+ftp+command

Comment: You can create script to connect and download and upload files with the ftp.exe console. https://ss64.com/nt/ftp.html